# How to handle deprecated gem warning (SourceIndex#all_gems)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, deprecated

Got this message today after running `bundle update`:

```
$ bundle update
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#all_gems is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#all_gems called from /Users/meltemi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@ppr3/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:256
.
```

Anyone know what it means and how to address it?

Note: This is a Rails 3.0.7 environment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the same errors for a bunch of my gems in a non-Rails environment when I upgraded to rubygems 1.8.0. I got the warnings any time rubygems is required. Looking around the 'Net, it seems like it might be a problem also with rubygems 1.7.x, but I never had one of those versions installed so I'm not sure. I fixed this by running:

```
gem pristine --all --no-extensions
```

I had to run it a few times - it kept erroring out (but usually not in the same place from run to run). Eventually it got far enough that it had addressed the majority of my gems.

There were a few gems that didn't get their specifications regenerated correctly (json and sequel, specifically in my case) because they needed to build an extension. (The gem command output indicated it was skipping them, though it was easy to miss that message amidst all the deprecation warnings.) For those gems, I uninstalled them and then reinstalled them again (they'd previously been installed by bundler in rubygems 1.5.x) and that fixed the remaining warnings. It may be that I could have started with that plan of attack originally, but I didn't try.

Comment: your answer led me to mine...my problem was twofold: had a few bad gems that had to be uninstalled and reinstalled (mysql2, json & nokogiri). and also had to run your `gem pristine --all --no-extensions` back on my *global* gemset where Bundler was. Now all is well... thanks!

Comment: I have this error on rake, and I can't seem to fix it by uninstall rake and reinstall

Comment: Sorry - no idea. I have rake 0.8.7 installed myself, and have no problems with it, related to RubyGems or not.

Comment: I was on rubygems 1.7.x and was constantly getting this error.  Upgraded to 1.8.1 (gem update --system) and it cleared it up.

Comment: And here I am thinking that hitting the same thing with a hammer over & over - is never useful in software... I was wrong ;-)

Answer (score 5):

It was called from the Bundler gem.  Try updating bundler to see if it helps

```
sudo gem update bundler
```

Comment: Updated Bundler to `1.0.13` (it was at `1.0.12` before) but warnings persist... Same deprecation warning appears before just about anything (`bundle show...`, `rake routes`, `rails s`, etc...)

Comment: Ironically the warning comes from the implementation that handles legacy versions of Gem.

Comment: This one worked for me... Now on bundler 1.1.0

Answer (score 1):

The Pry gem uses the rubygems API directly and can't be fixed by just running `gem pristine --all` unfortunately.

I forked the Pry gem and added fixes using non-deprecated API calls. Pending a merge to master, here is the fork: https://github.com/dvdplm/pry

Answer (score 1):

I updated bundler ('gem update bundler') from 1.0.12 to 1.0.15. Now all is well.

Answer (score 0):

Qoute:

> As far as I see from the sources:
>   Simply patch rubygems_integration.rb, line 256:
>       - Gem.source_index.all_gems.values
>       + Gem.source_index.gems.values
>   Reason:
>   Gem::SourceIndex#all_gems was just returning @gems, and now there is an 
>   attr_reader for @gems. I think that was the reason to remove the 
>   all_gems method.

Source: [ruby-forum.com](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1649001#997014)

Comment: Patching your gem isn't going to work very well since you'll have to patch it on each and every system affected by this. For some that could be dozens if not hundreds.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted and reinstalled ruby 1.9.2 via RVM and then uninstalled all gems:

```
gem list --no-versions
```

Put the result in a file called `gems` (cut out the error messages). Then do:

```
GEMS=`cat gems`
for x in $GEMS ; do gem uninstall $x -aIx; done
```

After that I was able to run the pristine command suggested by others:

```
gem pristine --all --no-extensions
```

That's when the errors disappeared.

Comment: If you want to do that quicker... `gem list --no-versions | xargs gem uninstall -aIx` and then run `gem pristine --all --no-extensions`

Answer (score 0):

**Bundler 1.0.13** (version released May 4, 2011) running with **rubygems 1.7.2** issues this annoying deprecation warning:

> NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#all_gems is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
> Gem::SourceIndex#all_gems called from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@composer/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:256

A [fix was committed](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/commit/9ad9d000d6427494dae21a67dd8e841985564d06) on 5/11/2011 in the Bundler repo [to correct an issue](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/1151) submitted 5/6/2011.

Pending release of Bundler 1.1, you can try this solution:

> $ gem uninstall bundler
>
> $ gem install bundler --version=1.0.12

I hope this helps. Took some digging to find it.

Comment: Bundler 1.0.14 is out and fixes this.