# Travis-ci build fails with rake aborted! LoadError: cannot load such file -- rspec/core/rake_task

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake, travis-ci

I'm trying to add travis-ci to my project and it keeps failing with

```
rake aborted! 
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rspec/core/rake_task
```

I'm currently using rspec 3.1

Any ideas as to why this is failing and how to fix it?

Here's my project that's failing:
https://github.com/toymachiner62/readable_date_ranges/tree/tests

EDIT

```
Using worker: worker-linux-9-2.bb.travis-ci.org:travis-linux-4
system_info
Build system information
Build language: ruby
git.checkout
0.62s$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master git://github.com/toymachiner62/readable_date_ranges.git toymachiner62/readable_date_ranges
Cloning into 'toymachiner62/readable_date_ranges'...
remote: Counting objects: 77, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (44/44), done.
remote: Total 77 (delta 28), reused 71 (delta 26)
Receiving objects: 100% (77/77), 13.73 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (28/28), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
$ cd toymachiner62/readable_date_ranges
$ git checkout -qf e78f9f7f350c2cfbb2ffb7751024a1bbb6ed732f
rvm
0.36s$ rvm use 1.9.3 --install --binary --fuzzy
Using /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p550 (2014-10-27 revision 48165) [x86_64-linux]
$ rvm --version
rvm 1.26.0 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
$ bundle --version
Bundler version 1.7.4
$ gem --version
2.4.2
0.82s$ rake
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rspec/core/rake_task
/home/travis/build/toymachiner62/readable_date_ranges/Rakefile:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The command "rake" exited with 1.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079495/problem-setting-up-rspec2-task-in-rakefile pretty old but maybe you find some ideas here

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your repository, after checkout you can see the differences:

Clone original repository:

> git clone https://github.com/kevinkaske/readable_date_ranges.git
>   kevinkaske_readable_date_ranges

Clone your own repository:

> git clone https://github.com/toymachiner62/readable_date_ranges.git
>   toymachiner62_readable_date_ranges

Now with tree, you can see that's some files missing in your repo, even if it's listed on github:

```
.
├── kevinkaske_readable_date_ranges
│   ├── GEMFILE
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── readable_date_ranges.rb
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── Rakefile
│   ├── readable_date_ranges.gemspec
│   ├── README.md
│   └── spec
│       ├── readable_date_ranges_spec.rb
│       └── spec_helper.rb
└── toymachiner62_readable_date_ranges
    ├── lib
    │   └── readable_date_ranges.rb
    ├── LICENSE
    ├── readable_date_ranges.gemspec
    └── README.md
```

So you don't have the `Rakefile`, which defines the rake tasks nor the `spec` directory.

**EDIT**

Add this to your `.travis.yaml` file:

```
# whitelist
branches:
  only:
    - test
```

Also try to put the travis YAML configuration file in the master branch.

Comment: I don't quite get it. How can files be missing if they are listed in the github repo? What are they missing from?

Comment: @Catfish If you check the repo now, they are not listed. You probably faced a cache issue.

Comment: They exist in my "tests" branch, not the master. The tests branch is what travis-ci failed on.

Comment: I tried to actually just merge with the master branch and that fails as well.

Answer (score 0):

My travis build too was aborted with the same error saying rake aborted.

To solve the issue, makesure to add the language attribute based on your application in your travis file.

If no language is needed, add generic language:

```
language: generic
```

For your ref, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67381391/14619383).

Comment: Have added the summary, please check it.