# Travis-CI Node.js Defaulting to Ruby Build? No RakeFile found

Tags: node.js, travis-ci

I'm posting this as a reference to others who have had the same problem.

```
$ rake
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The command "rake" exited with 1.
```

The above is output when building a Node.JS project on Travis-CI. The .travis.yml file is valid:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "0.12"
```

Comment: For me, it was a typo in `.travis.yml`. (language spelled as 'langauge')

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fix the .travis.yml by removing the quotations on the versioning, as follows:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 0.12
```

The Travis Node.JS docs currently display with quotation marks. This appears to be incorrect.

http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs/

If others can test to verify, please comment below.

EDIT: It's likely a temporary issue, as there are other examples of .travis.yml files with quotes on the version number (if it's nested in an include).

Comment: I'm assuming it's a temporary issue, as http://lint.travis-ci.org/ is validating the with quotes format is valid. And there are plenty of examples of nested versioning (such as in an include: ) that has quotes on the version numbers.

Comment: I read the docs on this in today and also saw [the version specified with quotes](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs/#default-build-script), I figured it may be due to some YAML weirdness so decided to follow suit... seems like a whopping 3+ years later quoted strings still aren't properly handled. [This](https://travis-ci.org/SidOfc/babel-plugin-transform-media-imports/builds/569962190) is a failing build using quoted strings. Retried without and node is [detected correctly](https://travis-ci.org/SidOfc/babel-plugin-transform-media-imports/builds/569970465).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error saying

```
$ rake
rake aborted!
```

In my case, I am using `.travis.yaml` file to push images to **DockerHub** and to deploy my app onto **GCP** from a local machine. So basically, I have commands related to **docker** and **GCP SDK**. Thus, I don't need any specific language.

So, I fixed the error by adding the

```
language: generic
```

line on the top of the `.travis.yaml` file.